# How to pass L^2 weak convergence and L^2 local convergence to L^2 strong convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $f_n$ be a sequence of non-negative and non-constant functions defined on $[0,1]$ with $f_n^{'}\leq 0$ on $[0,1]$ (if needed we can have $f_n^{'}(0)=0=f_n^{'}(1)$, I do not see this helps in the following argument. Also, $f_n$ is as smooth as you wish. Anything said about the convergence is up to a subsequence, but we still denote them by $f_n$ for notation convenience). Assume that the following integral equality holds:

$$
\int_0^1 f_n(x)dx=\int_0^1 f_n^2(x)dx. \tag{1}
$$
From (1) and Holder inequality, it follows easily that 
$$
\int_0^1 f_n(x)dx\leq 1, \quad \int_0^1 f_n^2(x)dx\leq 1. \tag{2}
$$
Thus, the uniform $L^2$ norm of $f_n$ ensures, up to a subsequence, that
 $$
f_n\rightharpoonup f \text{ weakly in }  L^2(0,l) \tag{3}
$$
for some $f\in L^2(0,1)$. Hence, by the definition of weak convergence, 
$$
\int_0^1 f_n(x)dx\rightarrow \int_0^1 f(x)dx. \tag{4}
$$
Also, since $f_n$ is non-increasing,  for any given $\epsilon>0$， we have from (2) that 
$$
f_n(\epsilon)\epsilon\leq \int_0^\epsilon f_n(x)dx\leq \int_0^1 f_n(x)dx\leq1, 
$$
which shows that $f_n$ is uniformaly bounded on $[\epsilon, 1]$. Then the Helly's selection principle gives, up to a subsequence, that 
$$f_n(x)\rightarrow f(x) \text{ pointwise on }(0,1]. \tag{5}
$$
With the help of Fatou' lemma, (5) and (4) imply 
 $$
f_n\rightarrow f \text{ strongly in }  L^1(0,l). \tag{6}
$$
Indeed, it is implied by 
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
2\int_0^1 f(x)dx&\leq\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_0^1f_n(x)+f(x)-|f_n(x)-f(x)|dx\\
&=2\int_0^1 f(x)dx-\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_0^1|f_n(x)-f(x)|dx. 
\end{array}
$$
Now, for any $p\in (1,2)$, using Holder and Minkowski inequalities, we infer from (3) and (6) that 
$$
\|f_n-f\|_p\leq\|f_n-f\|_1^{\frac{2-p}{p}}\|f_n-f\|_2^{\frac{2(p-1)}{p}}\leq 2^{\frac{2(p-1)}{p}}\|f_n-f\|_{L^1(0,l)}^{\frac{2-p}{p}} \rightarrow 0,
\rightarrow 0,
$$
which shows 
$$
f_n\rightarrow f\text{ strongly in }  L^p(0,l), \forall p\in [1,2). \tag{6}
$$
Recall that $f_n$ is uniformly bounded on $[\epsilon, 1], \forall \epsilon>0$. Hence, using (5) and the Lebesgue dominated convergence, one gets 
$$
f_n\rightarrow f\text{ strongly in }  L^2_{\text{loc}}(0,l).
$$
**Now, a critical and global question arises:  Do we have a global $L^2$ convergence: 
$$
f_n\rightarrow f\text{ strongly in }  L^2(0,l)\quad ? \tag{7}
$$ If not, please give me a counterexample**.  **A weak version of question(7): If we are given additionally that $f_n(x)\leq C(1+n)$, can (7) be true?**  Based on (5), to prove (7) it is necessary and sufficient to show 
$$
\int_0^1 f_n^2(x)dx\rightarrow \int_0^1 f^2(x)dx. \tag{8}
$$

I here note that,  on the one hand, if $f$ is a constant which is not 0 or 1, then (7) will never be true, because by (1) and (3), one has 
$$
\int_0^1|f_n-f|^2dx\rightarrow \int_0^1f(1-f)dx. 
$$
This actually gives the necessary condition for (7) being true. On the other hand, without monotonicity assumption, $f_n$ may not have a a.e. convergence subsequence, and thus it has no a strong convergence subsequence; see a similar question I asked. I also thought a more careful study on (1)  is important. Thank you!

Comment: Can you clarify what $\textbf{is}$ your question? I did not see a clear statement at here...

Comment: The question is whether (7) or its weak version is ture or not?